# Detect what position a div takes in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to know what position a div has in an argument: by this I mean, that if I have several divs witht the same name, like so:

```
<div class="woot"></div>
<div class="woot"></div>
<div class="woot"></div>
<div class="woot"></div>
<div class="woot"></div>
```

I would like to detect onclick what position the div click takes: 1st, 2nd....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="woot"></div>
   <div class="woot"></div>
   <div class="woot"></div>
   <div class="woot"></div>
   <div class="woot"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

   var woots = $(".parent").find(".woot");

   $(woots).each(function(index){
       $(this).attr("data-position", index);
   });

   $(".parent").on("click", ".woot", function(){
       console.log($(this).data("position"));
   });
});

</script>
```

You should see the position in the console if you are running it in a browser like Chrome, for example.

Comment: Slightly overdone, don't you think?

Comment: Compared to your answer yes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the index() function, it will return a zero-based index of the clicked element within the selection:

```
$('.woot').click(function(){
    var clickedIndex = $('.woot').index($(this));
})
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/xtbu13gh/